# Disabling IPv6 DNS resolution on client only to a specific domain

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I want to connect to my company's extranet. However, I can't from my domain-joined laptop when it's at home, though I can when at the office, or a non-domain joined machine at home. The difference appears to be IPv6:

- Domain-joined laptop, at office: Connects fine, ping shows `IPv4` address.
- Domain-joined laptop, at home: Fails to connect, ping shows `IPv6` address.
- Non-domain-joined machine, at home: Connects fine, ping shows `IPv4` address.

Possible workaround:

- Add the IPv4 address to my `hosts` file. CON: If the extranet address ever changes, I'll be stuck with the old address.
- Disable IPv6 on the machine, or some of its connections. CON: I believe connectivity to other work machines depends on it.

So, is there a way to tell Windows "For this specific domain, use only IPv4"?

Comment: Have you got IPv6 at home? Does the _company_ have it at work?

Comment: @Michael: No IPv6 at home - neither my router nor my ISP offer it. The company's intranet is both IPv4 and IPv6. I believe the company uses [DirectAccess](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn636118.aspx) and deploys it on my laptop, though I don't know the details.

Comment: Have you spoken to the helpdesk yet? I suspect that something else strange is going on that none of us have any idea about.